# How to insert simultaneously same data into two differentes table on delphi

Tags: sql, database, delphi, paradox

I have two tables 
purchase and stock (paradox 7 in delphi),
so I want when I insert some new data in the table "purchase" will be added simultaneously in "stock" table.

If someone knows how it works or else say how to do it with SQL.

Comment: Start transaction, write what you want, commit. Or create a trigger that will do that for you (I would prefer manual writing before trigger though).

Comment: One has to wonder why you're using such an ancient / dead software (Paradox 7). I sure hope it's only for the purpose of upgrading customers to newer technology.

Comment: what you man by simultaneously?? did you mean, that if writing in `purchase` table did not succeed, stop writing in `stock`  and vise versa , like a `transaction`?

Comment: Been a while since I've used Paradox, but as @Victoria says, use transactions. Check out http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examin95.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 Tquery (master + detail).
Assemble instructions and relationships.
Put a Provider, connect it to the tquery-Master.
Place 2 TClientDataset.
Connect the 1st to the provider (providername)
The second call tdatasetfield for the 2nd Query (detail).